# Bose Color II SoundLink Bluetooth Speaker Volume Adjustment Disabled

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I have a Bose Color II SoundLink Bluetooth Speaker connected on Ubuntu 19.10. The sound works but the volume buttons on the speaker are disabled when connected. It sounds like speaker volume is stuck at 25% when the Ubuntu volume is on 100%.

I did a comparison test with my Android phone. I played a music video and I was able to physically adjust the volume on the speaker without issue. It got very loud at the cafe here.

I played the same music video on Firefox and the volume sounds about 25% of what this speaker can do where:

- the system volume up to 100%
- the browser volume up to 100%, and
- the YouTube player volume up 100%.

Any ideas on how I can troubleshoot and hopefully solve this? Would love to use Ubuntu with Bose to listen to music and watch movies at an exciting volume!

**TROUBLESHOOTING**

1. Install pavucontrol

I installed pavucontrol and see nothing that may address this situation, correct me if I've missing something:

```
max@msi:~$ sudo apt install pavucontrol
[sudo] password for max: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  pavucontrol
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 126 kB of archives.
After this operation, 955 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 pavucontrol amd64 3.0-4 [126 kB]
Fetched 126 kB in 1s (119 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package pavucontrol.
(Reading database ... 198776 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pavucontrol_3.0-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pavucontrol (3.0-4) ...
Setting up pavucontrol (3.0-4) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.7-3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.63ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.32.0-1ubuntu1) ...
max@msi:~$ pavucontrol
```

[image]

Comment: Anything you can adjust by `pavucontrol`?

Comment: @jarno please see updated question

Comment: It seems that you can adjust volume over 100 percent.

Comment: This control has no effect over the physical volume of the speaker. The speaker is frozen at about 25%. This will adjustment at 100% is the 25% I mention. More than that just is virtual and causes distortion.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the output devices with this command;

```
>>pactl list short sinks

0   alsa_output.pci-0320_00_2b.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
4   bluez_sink.ZZ_AA_AA_AA_AA_XD.a2dp_sink  module-bluez5-device.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   RUNNING
```

The first column indicates the index of device.

Then set the volume (e.g.) from 100% to 200% for the device with index **4**. This index can be different for you local.

```
>>sudo pactl -- set-sink-volume 4 200%
```