# Bose Color II SoundLink Keeps Disconnecting on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, 19.10

[Bose Color II SoundLink](https://www.bose.com/en_us/products/speakers/portable_speakers/soundlink-color-bluetooth-speaker-ii.html#v=soundlink_color_ii_midnight_blue)  will connect but immediately disconnects on Ubuntu 19.10.

*Because I did not see a question that addresses the exact situation with an answer, I wrote this question so others may find the answer easier.*

My answer is referenced from this question: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689281/pulseaudio-can-not-load-bluetooth-module)

Although, there still is a speaker adjustment problem in which I have further addressed with this question: [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1211475/bose-color-ii-soundlink-bluetooth-speaker-volume-adjustment-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Enter this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install bluetooth pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
```

Reboot and now the speaker will stay connected.